# Which Objects are displayed in PermissionSet Object Settings?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, sobject, standard-objects, permission-sets, describesobject

I am a noob with Salesforce, please bare with my question.

I am creating an App which enables easy edit/creation of PermissionSets on an ORG.

In this process, I am creating a tree view with

> Permission Sets **-->**     Objects + Permissions **-->** 
>          Fields + Permissions

**Step 1.** I have retrieved Permission Sets with SOQL

```
SELECT Id,Name,Description,NamespacePrefix,UserLicenseId,CreatedDate FROM PermissionSet
```

**Step 2.** I am retrieving Objects with
`Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`

Here is my question, I am able to fetch all the objects from my ORG, but the object names does not match with the object names which we generally see in **Permission Set --> Object Settings**

**For example:**

With `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`, I get the Object Names, something like this,

```
Label: Contract, Name: Contract

Label: Contract History, Name: ContractHistory

Label: Order, Name: Order

Label: Order Share, Name: OrderShare
```

but, in Permission Set -> Object Settings I see something like this,

```
Accounts    
App Launcher    
Assets  
Campaign Members    
Campaigns   
Cases   
Chatter 
Coaching    
Coaching    
Contacts    
Content 
Contracts
```

All I need is same set of object Names as we see in **Permission Set -> Object Settings**

I read that the object names displayed in **Permission Set -> Object Settings** are the whole set of objects from ORG but, I see some of them are missing and some are different with just being singular to plural like,

**From my code:** "Case"

**From Permission Set --> Object Settings:** "Cases"

Btw, I am doing all of it in Lightning components

Thanks!

Updates:

**This is the output I see when using,

AllObjectsofOrg = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        List AllObjs = new List();

```
    if(!AllObjectsofOrg.isEmpty()) {

        for(String key:AllObjectsofOrg.keySet())
        {
            AllObjs.add(key+'!@#'+AllObjectsofOrg.get(key).getDescribe().getLabelPlural());
        }
    }
    return AllObjs;
```

**

1. Object Name: Contracts
2. app.js:44 Object Name: Contract History
3. app.js:44 Object Name: Contract Feed
4. app.js:44 Object Name: Orders
5. app.js:44 Object Name: Order Share
6. app.js:44 Object Name: Order History
7. app.js:44 Object Name: Order Feed
8. app.js:44 Object Name: Order Products
9. app.js:44 Object Name: Order Product History
10. app.js:44 Object Name: Order Product Feed
11. app.js:44 Object Name: Contract Contact Role
12. app.js:44 Object Name: Opportunity Stage
13. app.js:44 Object Name: Lead Status Value
14. app.js:44 Object Name: Case Status Value
15. app.js:44 Object Name: Solution Status Value
16. app.js:44 Object Name: Partner Role Value
17. app.js:44 Object Name: Task Priority Value
18. app.js:44 Object Name: Task Status Value
19. app.js:44 Object Name: Contract Status Value
20. app.js:44 Object Name: Record Types
21. app.js:44 Object Name: Business Process
22. app.js:44 Object Name: Organizations
23. app.js:44 Object Name: Mail Merge Template
24. app.js:44 Object Name: Custom S-Controls
25. app.js:44 Object Name: Documents
26. app.js:44 Object Name: Folders
27. app.js:44 Object Name: Email Status
28. app.js:44 Object Name: Custom Buttons or Links
29. app.js:44 Object Name: Email Templates
30. app.js:44 Object Name: Document Entity Map
31. app.js:44 Object Name: Letterheads
32. app.js:44 Object Name: Names
33. app.js:44 Object Name: Recently Viewed
34. app.js:44 Object Name: Login History
35. app.js:44 Object Name: Login IP
36. app.js:44 Object Name: Client Browser
37. app.js:44 Object Name: Votes
38. app.js:44 Object Name: Zones
39. app.js:44 Object Name: Aggregate Result
40. app.js:44 Object Name: Campaigns
41. app.js:44 Object Name: Campaign Share
42. app.js:44 Object Name: Campaign Feed
43. app.js:44 Object Name: Campaign Member Status
44. app.js:44 Object Name: Campaign Members
45. app.js:44 Object Name: Accounts
46. app.js:44 Object Name: Account Share
47. app.js:44 Object Name: Account History
48. app.js:44 Object Name: Account Feed
49. app.js:44 Object Name: Contacts
50. app.js:44 Object Name: Contact Share
51. app.js:44 Object Name: Contact History
52. app.js:44 Object Name: Contact Feed
53. app.js:44 Object Name: Leads
54. app.js:44 Object Name: Lead Share
55. app.js:44 Object Name: Lead History
56. app.js:44 Object Name: Lead Feed
57. app.js:44 Object Name: Opportunities
58. app.js:44 Object Name: Opportunity Share
59. app.js:44 Object Name: Opportunity Field History
60. app.js:44 Object Name: Opportunity Feed
61. app.js:44 Object Name: Opportunity Contact Role
62. app.js:44 Object Name: Opportunity History
63. app.js:44 Object Name: Opportunity Product
64. app.js:44 Object Name: Opportunity: Competitor
65. app.js:44 Object Name: Partner
66. app.js:44 Object Name: Account Partner
67. app.js:44 Object Name: Opportunity Partner
68. app.js:44 Object Name: Forecast Share

**and many more.
where as, in Salesforce Permission Set -> Object Settings**

1. Accounts
2. App Launcher
3. Assets
4. Campaign Members
5. Campaigns
6. Cases
7. Chatter
8. Coaching
9. Coaching
10. Contacts
11. Content
12. Contracts
13. D&B Companies
14. Dashboards
15. Data.com
16. Documents
17. Duplicate Record Items
18. Duplicate Record Sets
19. Events
20. Expenses
21. Feedback
22. Feedback Questions
23. Feedback Question Sets
24. Feedback Requests
25. Feedback Templates
26. Files
27. Forecasts
28. Global
29. Goal Links
30. Goals
31. Goals
32. Groups
33. Home
34. Ideas
35. Leads
36. Libraries
37. Macros
38. Metric Data Links
39. Metrics
40. Opportunities
41. Opportunity Product
42. Order Products
43. Orders
44. Outlook
45. People
46. Performance Cycles
47. Price Book Entries
48. Price Books
49. Products
50. Profile
51. Profile Coaching
52. Profile Feed
53. Profile Feedback
54. Profile Goals
55. Profile Overview
56. Push Topics
57. Reports
58. Site.com
59. Social Personas
60. Solutions
61. Streaming Channels
62. Subscriptions
63. Tasks
64. User Provisioning Requests
65. Users

**which are comparatively less and different.
like, some of them are different with being plural and some are missing.**

Example:

In the list from my code:

1. Contracts
2. Contract History
3. Contract Feed

where as in the list from Permission Set-> Object Settings, I see only

1. Contracts

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make use of [**Schema.describeSobjects**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm#apex_System_Schema_describeSObjects). This will return you [**Schema.DescribeSobjectResult**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe). Use the **[getLabelPlural()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getLabelPlural)** method from **Schema.DescribeSobjectResult** to get the desired output.

> **Schema.describeSobjects** - Describes metadata (field list and object properties) for the specified sObject or array of sObjects.
>
> **Schema.DescribeSobjectResult** - Contains methods for describing sObjects
>
> **getLabelPlural** - Returns the object's plural label, which may or may not match the object name.

Below is the code snippet which will give you the desired output:

```
// get the objects in the org
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

// remove the unwanted objects like share, history, tag, feed etc
for(String s : gd.keySet()){
  if(s.toLowerCase().contains('history') || s.toLowerCase().contains('tag') 
    || s.toLowerCase().contains('share') || s.toLowerCase().contains('feed')){
     gd.keyset().remove(s);
}   

// remove the faq__kav as it doesnt seem to be supported in describeSObjects. We will add it later once we describe other objects.
gd.keyset().remove('**mynamespace**__faq__kav');

// list to store the object names
List<String> objNames = new List<String>();
objNames.addAll(gd.keyset());

// get the properties of each object like label, plural label, key prefix, isCreatable, isUpdatable etc..
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult[] descResult = Schema.describeSObjects(objNames);

// add the **mynamespace**__faq__kav which we removed in line 12
descResult.add(**mynamespace**__faq__kav.getSObjectType().getDescribe());

// store the plural labels of the result returned above in the list
List<String> pluralLabels = new List<String>();
for(Schema.DescribeSObjectResult res: descResult){
    pluralLabels.add(res.getLabelPlural());        
}
```

Comment: Hey Shailesh, Thank you for responding. My question still persists, please check the updates in my question.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the user logged in can only access/view only certain objects and not ALL? thus, with UI (Permission Set -> Object Settings) I am able to fetch only certain objects and with code I am able to fetch ALL objects from my ORG??

Comment: I dont think that is the issue here. getGlobalDescribe will return you all the objects in your org. Also even if you dont have access to certain object, you would still see that object in the Permission Set --> Object Settings... The objects that are not available in Permission Set --> Object Settings are the -- history, share, tag, feed, objects like "Apex Class", "Apex Trigger" etc. So you might have to skip those objects while generating the list. Updated the code.. It would be best to store those in a custom setting and remove them.

Comment: If that is the case, in my return data ( according to my question) from GetGlobalDescribe is returning heck a lot of data i.e., many object names compared to Permission Set -> Object Settings. Why do u think so?

Comment: Thru your code, removing it with Text comparison will not do the needful as it'll remove all Objects (Names) with 'Feed' (as an example) in it. This way I may loose any object which is actually present in Permission Sets -> Object Settings like, 'Feedback', 'Feedback Questions', 'Feedback Question Sets', 'Feedback Requests' etc.

Comment: There should be (I guess so) some conditional value which would opt out all objects which are not shown under Permission Sets -> Object Settings. I appreciate your help **Shailesh**